# TensorFlow .js Simple Model to Predict 2 Table multiple is not Showing Correct Output?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

i have made a tensorflow.js model to predict the output in multiple of two for example 16 should predict 32 like that and given the input data and label accordingly still output which printed is **[[1],]** after **prediction.print()**

Code : -

```
const data = tf.tensor([2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30])
const label = tf.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])

const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape : [1], units : 32, activation : 'relu'}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units : 1, activation : 'softmax'}))   

model.compile({
    optimizer:'sgd',
    loss:'meanSquaredError',
    metrics:['accuracy']
})
function onBatchEnd (batch,logs){
   // console.log(logs.acc)
}
model.fit(data,label,{
epochs: 50,
batchSize : 4,
callbacks:{onBatchEnd}
}).then(info =>{
    console.log(info.history.acc);
    const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor([16]))
    prediction.print() 
})
```

**Output By Prediction.print() is [[1],]**

and please explaint the meaning of inputshape here how to define which inputshape to give for example if i am having a tensor = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
so what will be the inputshape for this and please give the link to study activation function such as relu and softmax and **does output layer unit should be one (1)only if i give anything other than one it gives error ?(Explanation Not clear)**

Answer (score 0):

The activation function for the last layer can't be `softmax`. `softmax` is used when performing classification task. Which is not the case here.

The official website of tensorflow has tons of example. Looking at your data and label, it seems that you inverted them. If you want to predict 32 from 16, 32 is the feature (data in your case ) and 32 the label. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898019/what-is-the-difference-between-a-feature-and-a-label) is a link to understand the difference between features and labels.

If you want to predict from 2 values, then the inputShape will be of Shape `[2]`. Simpy put the InputShape is the shape of the single element you would like to predict from. If one wants to predict from :

- `[1, 2]`, the inputShape will be 2
- `[[2, 4, 5], [5, 6, 3]]`, the inputShape will be [2, 3]

and so on ...

**model with inputShape [1]**

```js
const data = tf.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
const label = tf.tensor([2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30])

const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape : [1], units : 32, activation : 'relu'}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units : 1}))   

model.compile({
    optimizer:'sgd',
    loss:'meanSquaredError',
    metrics:['accuracy']
})
function onBatchEnd (batch,logs){
   // console.log(logs.acc)
}
model.fit(data, label, {
epochs: 50,
callbacks:{onBatchEnd}
}).then(info =>{
    console.log(info.history.acc);
    const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor([16]))
    prediction.print() 
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**model with inputShape [2]**

```js
const data = tf.tensor([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14]])

const label = tf.tensor([[2,4],[6,8],[10,12],[14,16],[18,20],[22,24],[26,28]])

const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape : [2], units : 32, activation : 'relu'}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units : 2}))   

model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.001),
    loss:'meanSquaredError',
    metrics:['accuracy']
})
function onBatchEnd (batch,logs){
   // console.log(logs.acc)
}
model.fit(data, label, {
epochs: 50,
callbacks:{onBatchEnd}
}).then(info =>{
    console.log(info.history.acc);
    const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor([[12, 13]]))
    prediction.print() 
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx for correcting for features and label . The code you provided is not predicting the output its giving 7 or 15 so how to correct it ? From where to study Activation function that which one to use where ? And Why you removed batch size from the code in model.fit ?